# How to execute django commands from another django project?

Tags: python, django, command

I have two django project on the same server.

Project 1 : is running (with gunicorn) to receive rest request and display data.

Project 2: is used only to execute django commands and is not running.

I would like to run a command from project2 inside project1 but when i do nothing is happening.

I tried :

```
Popen(["/opt/xxx/venv3/bin/python", "/opt/xxx/src/manage.py", "custom_commands", "params"])
os.system("/opt/xxx/venv3/bin/python /opt/xxx/src/manage.py custom_commands params")
```

without success (i tried to read the ouput of Popen but it's empty).

When i run the same command inside a python shell on the server it works so its must be related to calling a django command from another django project.

----Edit----

I managed to read the stderr with popen and i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/opt/project2/venv3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command\n    app_name = commands[subcommand]\nKeyError: \'mail_lre\'\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/opt/project2/src/manage.py", line 22, in <module>\n    main()\n  File "/opt/project2/src/manage.py", line 18, in main\n    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)\n  File "/opt/project2/venv3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line\n    utility.execute()\n  File "/opt/project2/venv3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute\n    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)\n  File "/opt/project2/venv3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 231, in fetch_command\n    settings.INSTALLED_APPS\n  File "/opt/project2/venv3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__\n    self._setup(name)\n  File "/opt/project2/venv3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup\n    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\n  File "/opt/project2/venv3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__\n    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module\n  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n  File "/opt/editik/src/Editik_django/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>\n    from utils.apps import app_ready\n  File "/opt/project2/src/utils/apps.py", line 15, in <module>\n    from api.settings import LOG_EDITIK_DIR\n  File "/opt/project2/src/api/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>\n    from utils.apps import app_ready\nImportError: cannot import name \'app_ready\' from partially initialized module \'utils.apps\' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/project2/src/utils/apps.py)
```

Really weird since it's working outside django project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i solved it by adding --pythonpath and --settings at the end of my command.

Like :

```
Popen(["/opt/xxx/venv3/bin/python", "/opt/xxx/src/manage.py", "custom_commands", "params", "--pythonpath='/opt/xxx/src/'", "--settings='api.settings'"])

os.system("/opt/xxx/venv3/bin/python /opt/xxx/src/manage.py custom_commands params --pythonpath='/opt/xxx/src/' --settings='app.settings'")
```